# Sorting images by their ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sorting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to sort LI's based on their ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3630397/how-to-sort-lis-based-on-their-id)

I have a div that is dynamically populated with various images and looks something like:

```
<div id="images">
<img id="img1" src="..." />
<img id="img3" src="..." />
<img id="img2" src="..." />
<img id="img6" src="..." />
<img id="img5" src="..." />
<img id="img4" src="..." />
</div>
```

Using javascript and jQuery, i need to sort the images into order of ID but i'm struggling. Heres what I've got so far:

```
var toSort = $('#images').children;
toSort = Array.prototype.slice.call(toSort,0);


toSort.sort(function(a,b){
   var aord = +a.id.substr(6);
   var bord = +b.id.substr(6);  
   return aord - bord; 
});


var parent = $('#images');
parent.innerHTML="";
for(var i=0, l = toSort.length; i<l; ++i){
   parent.appendChild(toSort[i]);
}
```

How close am I? What am I doing wrong? Thanks guys.

Comment: Is there a problem with your code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var imgs = $('#images img');
imgs.sort(function(a, b) {
   return a.id > b.id;
});
$('#images').html(imgs);
​
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/CY46R/4/)**

**OR**

```
var imgs = $('#images img');
imgs.sort(function(a, b) {
   return +a.id.replace('img','') -  +b.id.replace('img','');
});
$('#images').html(imgs);
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/CY46R/6/)**

Edition with your code:

```
var parent = $('#images'),
    children = parent.children(),
    toSort = Array.prototype.slice.call(children, 0);

parent[0].innerHTML = ""; //or parent.empty();

toSort.sort(function(a, b) {
    var aord = +a.id.substr(3);
    var bord = +b.id.substr(3);
    return aord - bord;
});

for (var i = 0; i < toSort.length; i++) {
    parent.append(toSort[i]);
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5JTQn/3/)**

Comment: The `.sort` callback should return an integer (`< 0`, `0` or `> 0`), not a boolean.

Comment: alternatively you can use return (a.id > b.id) ? 1 : (a.id < b.id) ? -1 : 0; but i dont think that 2 images will have the same id so it will have the same result

Comment: I've tried to use the bottom example but I'm getting the error "Object doesn't support property or method 'sort'"? Any ideas as to why?

Comment: @user1055650 do you try with exactly my demo?

Comment: @user1055650 `.substr(6)` has some problem, I think because `id` in your post has not that length. it should `substr(3)`

Comment: I eventually got this working using your third example. Thank you so much for your time!

Answer (score 0):

```
var elem = $('#images'),
    imgs = elem.find('img');
imgs.sort(function(a, b) {
   return a.id.toUpperCase().localeCompare(b.id.toUpperCase());
});
$.each(imgs, function(idx, itm) { elem.append(itm); });
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/GgnF3/4/)

Answer (score 0):

I think @thecodeparadox version is better but here is your code corrected a little bit. I changed img to span to make it more visible.

http://jsfiddle.net/whnyn/